# webview_flutter gives a blank page when loading a stripe checkout page in production mode

Tags: flutter, webview, stripe-payments, webview-flutter

I've integrated a Stripe checkout page via a webview in Flutter. if I use stripe's test mode everything works perfectly, but as soon as I switch to production mode, the webview is completely blank.
In the stripe console I can see that the page gets loaded and the payment is canceled every time I hit back on the phone, so the stripe page is working. Any suggestion?

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:buildabuild/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

const String stripeHtmlPage = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<head><title>Stripe checkout</title></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
''';

class CheckoutScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String sessionId;

  const CheckoutScreen(
    this.sessionId, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CheckoutScreenState createState() => _CheckoutScreenState();
}

class _CheckoutScreenState extends State<CheckoutScreen> {
  late WebViewController _webViewController;
  String get initialUrl =>
      'data:text/html;base64,${base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(stripeHtmlPage))}';

  void _redirectToStripe() {
    final redirectToCheckoutJs = '''
var stripe = Stripe('$stripePublishableKeyProd');
    
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId: '${widget.sessionId}'
}).then(function (result) {
  result.error.message = 'Error'
});
''';
    _webViewController.runJavascript(redirectToCheckoutJs);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: initialUrl,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) =>
              _webViewController = webViewController,
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            if (url == initialUrl) {
              _redirectToStripe();
            }
          },
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url == 'https://success.com/') {
              Get.back(result: 'OK');
            } else if (request.url == 'https://cancel.com/') {
              Get.back(result: 'KO');
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experimentally discovered that hosting the page and serving it via a service (I used Firebase Hosting, but for sure it will work also with other services), opening directly the page fixed the problem. However I don't know why, if someone has ideas he/she 's welcome.

The new code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class CheckoutScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String sessionId;

  const CheckoutScreen(
    this.sessionId, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: '***hosting_address***/checkout.html?sessionId=$sessionId',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url == 'https://success.com/') {
              Get.back(result: 'OK');
            } else if (request.url == 'https://cancel.com/') {
              Get.back(result: 'KO');
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's because stripe.js requires you to use a page with a https:// origin(in livemode), there are warnings/errors about that in the browser console. So what you were doing before constructing your own HTML page not served over https won't work.

Comment: By the way you don't need `stripe.redirectToCheckout` (it used to be required but Stripe removed that requirement last year). If you get the URL from your backend you can just redirect directly to that without using Stripe's JS library.  https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url

Comment: Thanks to karllekko . I used url from the response of backend. The response contains a stripe session object which has a url field. Simply pass the value to the webview.